# Referencing a local variable while iterate a HashMap -> local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final error

Tags: java, variables, lambda

today i wanted to work on some projects i wanted to finish where i get an exception that i can not reference to a local variable from a lambda expression.
I have a method where i give two values and th method checks if the value-pair is already in the HashMap

```
public void METHOD_NAME(Value value1, Value value2) {
    boolean founded = false;
  //values is the name of the HashMap
    this.values.forEach((value1Map, value2Map) -> {
            if(value1Map == value1&&value2Map == value2){
                this.doSomeStuff();
                founded = true;
            }

    });

}
```

and when its finished i want to read out the boolean needing to know if he doesent found it
founded = false; 
how can i set founded in this lambda or are there any other ways to do this ?

Comment: find -> found ... "founded" has a different meaning.

Comment: [This](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=local+variables+referenced+from+a+lambda+expression+must+be+final+or+effectively+final&gws_rd=cr&ei=5S8gWcehKKnAgAbBioDQDQ) should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the atomic variants of primitives in lambdas. Replace

```
boolean founded = true
```

by this

```
final AtomicBoolean found = new AtomicBoolean(false);
```

and set it in within your lambda like this

```
found.set(true);
```

By the way, it is absolutely ok NOT to replace every iteration by a lambda. The for-loop still works and has its advantages over lambdas in some cases.

I've changed *founded* to *found* as Tom indicated in the comments of your question. Moreover, you should verify if you want to make the comparison with `==` instead of `equals`

Comment: At first thank you for the fast answer it now works thank you ;) Ive used the lambda because i thought it seem to be easier to iterate trough an HashMap using it

Comment: You're welcome. In your case I'd prefer the for-loop because of the workaround with AtomicBoolean and because you call no other methods of the stream API than forEach. Eventually it's personal preference. Consider to mark my answer as accepted solution. Thanks